# estimator and variance

Tags: statistics

Let $\mu,\alpha_n:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ continuous function with $\mu$ bounded function.
Let $N^{(n)}$ the trajectory of a Poisson process with intensity $(\alpha_n \mu)(t)$.
Let $0=T_0^{(n)}<T_1^{(n)}<..$ jumps of $N^{(n)}$.

Let $M_n(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N_t^{(n)}} \frac {1} {\alpha_n (T_i^{(n)})}$ and $M(t)=\int_0^t \mu(s)ds$

Calculate $E((Mn(t)-M(t))^2)$?

Before I showed that $M_n(t)$ was an unbiased estimator of M(t)
But here I don't see how to solve the question

Can you help me?

Thank you